# Find the supremum of holomorphic functions from semiplane to disk.

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider all the holomorphic functions $f:P\to B_1(0)$ with $f(1)=0$ where $z\in P$ iff $\text{Re} z>0$.

I want to find the supremum of $|f(2)|$ over all such $f$.

I thought about using a Möbius transformation sending $B_1(0)$ to $P$ and $0\mapsto 1$ (or unrestricted) and then applying Schwarz Lemma (or Schwarz-Pick) to the composite to find some bound. Then finding a function which takes that value. But is this the right approach? I don't know if such a function exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\tau(z) = \tfrac{1+z}{1-z}$ is a biholomorphic transformation mapping $B_1(0)$ bijectively to $P$. As $\tau(\tfrac 1 3) = 2$, you get $|f(2)| = |f(\tau(\tfrac 1 3))| \le\tfrac 1 3$ by the Schwarz lemma. Since $\tau^{-1} : P\to B_1(0)$ and $\tau^{-1}(2) = \tfrac 1 3$, the supremum is $\tfrac 1 3$.